# Show location of file in git repository?

Tags: git

I have a file `Foo.txt` in my git repository and I want to know where it is located.

I could use `find . -name Foo.txt` to search the filesystem for this file, but this has a couple issues:

1. I have a lot of untracked directories, and I don't care about any coincidental `Foo.txt` files that exist in them
2. I have a lot of untracked directories, and `find` will waste a ton of time searching them pointlessly

However, I know that `git` indexes all the files in the repository and can return them extremely fast. If I do `git ls-files` it will print out all tracked files in the repository in milliseconds.

So I can indeed do `git ls-files | grep Foo.txt` when I want to find the file, but:

1. I feel like I shouldn't have to type the `| grep` and I'm a lazy bum that would rather ask this on StackOverflow than type `| grep` in perpetuity every time I want to do this forever more.
2. This feels like the `cat Foo.txt | grep some_pattern` [problem](https://bencane.com/2013/08/19/grepping-a-file-without-using-cat-and-grep-other-tricks/) where *you should just do* `grep some_pattern Foo.txt`
3. An angel loses their wings every time you send a giant blob of text to `stdout` and grep for what you want *instead of using the tool for what it was designed for*
4. OK yes I could define a function in my `.zshrc` that does this, but that can't be The Right Way™ can it??

Additionally the `git-ls-files` [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) does not seem to indicate that what I want is possible. Am I doomed to grepping the output of `git ls-files` via a custom defined zshrc function forever?

Comment: I wanted to make a comment about how `git ls-files | grep Foo.txt` feels like the kind of composition that the Unix philosophy would advocate for, but that would fly in the face of the fact that `git` itself is a large complex program with lots of subcommands.

Comment: But if you just want nice syntax, I guess you can add a git alias in your `gitconfig`? Something like `[alias] find = !git ls-files | grep $1`

Comment: Unix is built around composing commands with pipes. Grepping the output of `git ls-files` is nothing compared to actually traversing the file tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I can use something like this:

```
git ls-files '*Foo.txt*'
```

I haven't checked edge cases, but in my tests, the output seems to be the same as the one from grep. (Here, `'*config.js*'` will match any `tsconfig.json` file, just like the grep version).

The quotation marks are necessary (without them, it'll just check the current folder, because the shell expands the asterisks)

Answer (score 3):

Try [pathspec magic](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec),

```
git ls-files -- ':(glob)**/Foo.txt'
```

But I think `grep` is simpler considering the number of words.